# Scrapy KeyError - Can't find spider

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've got a scrapy project that will not execute with `scrapy crawl <spider-name>` from the command line.

I've just moved to a new development environment on ubuntu 16.04 so I wanted to double check that the issue wasn't with my set up. To do so, I created a clean virtual environment with `virtualenvwrapper` using `python 2.7.12` and followed the [tutorial instructions](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/intro/tutorial.html#how-to-run-our-spider) from the Scrapy docs. (v1.1 to mimic my other project).

Despite the new environment, I am still seeing odd behaviour from scrapy, where it won't:

- list the spiders `scrapy list`
- list the settings `scrapy settings`
- start a crawl `scrapy crawl quotes`

`scrapy crawl quotes` raises the following error:

```
2017-01-06 14:20:50 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2017-01-06 14:20:50 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alan/QueryClick/.virtualenvs/test/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/alan/QueryClick/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/home/alan/QueryClick/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/alan/QueryClick/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/home/alan/QueryClick/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/home/alan/QueryClick/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 162, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/home/alan/QueryClick/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 190, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/home/alan/QueryClick/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 194, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/home/alan/QueryClick/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 43, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: quotes'
```

My directory structure is:

```
└── tutorial
    ├── scrapy.cfg
    └── tutorial
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── items.py
        ├── pipelines.py
        ├── settings.py
        └── spiders
            ├── __init__.py
            └── quote_spider.py
```

I've also double checked all my system requirements, as specified in the Scrapy documentation. This issue is replicated across my team, on Ubuntu 14.04 following the same steps with a virtualenv and an identical setup to mine.

If anyone can shed any light on this, I would be eternally grateful.

---

**Edit**: Adding `settings.py`

The only things active in `settings.py` are:

```
BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
```

---

**Edit:** Sharing `scrapy.cfg`

```
# Automatically created by: scrapy startproject
#
# For more information about the [deploy] section see:
# https://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html

[settings]
default = tutorial.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = tutorial
```

Comment: please share your `settings.py` file the `SPIDER_MODULES` variable

Comment: @eLRuLL - added now. Very basic because I am following the tutorial.

Comment: please share also the content of `scrapy.cfg`

Comment: what do `scrapy list` and `scrapy settings` output?

Comment: @paultrmbrth - no output - I've put an `ipdb` in `/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py` and inspected manually - it's a empty list.

Comment: @eLRuLL shared `scrapy.cfg`

Comment: and what's in `quote_spider.py`? does it define a "name" attribute?

Comment: @paultrmbrth it certainly does 
`class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "quotes"`

Comment: It's not my first rodeo with scrapy - the other project I refer too is deployed with scrapyd on a live server, I just can't get either that project or the tutorial project to work in my or my colleagues venev.

Comment: and you're running your commands at same level as `scrapy.cfg` I believe. I have no idea what's happening, sorry.

Comment: @AlanHannah no output at all with `scrapy list`, please share what it outputs if something.

Comment: Can you `ipdb` in [`_load_all_spiders`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/d19c4c1f809aae47f12637ea6f465127f728451c/scrapy/spiderloader.py#L31) to check if it's looking into the correct modules?

Comment: Sorry chaps - see below - found the issue, it's my naming of environment varialbles.

Answer (score 0):

This was a conflict with some environment variables that had been set for a django project that calls the spider - they were namespaced with `SCRAPY_` and must have been conflicting.

**Edit:** For reference: [GitHub issue on undocumented environment variable(s)](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1109)

Comment: it is still good to know about what else can break scrapy's configuration, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your spider is .py, if created from jupyter for example, it might be .ipynb which will not be picked up.